# I have some error when I upgrade through terminal in kali OS

Tags: kali-linux, error-handling

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnustep-base-runtime : Depends: gnustep-base-common (= 1.29.0-4) but 1.28.1+really1.28.0-5 is to be installed
 libgnustep-base1.29 : Depends: gnustep-base-common (= 1.29.0-4) but 1.28.1+really1.28.0-5 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

[image]

Please give any suggestion

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They can't be searched, can be difficult to read, and cannot be copied to a shell. Is `gnustep` coming from a Kali repository because the latest version I see in Kali is 1.26.0?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux distribution geared towards various information security tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux. This is unwise.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594257/debian-bullseye-no-upgrade-due-to-gnustep-base-runtime-unmet-dependencies